# How to preserve stack trace in this case?

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube, stack-trace, pmd

In my code I got a rule violation called 'preserve stack trace' while I have analysed the code on sonar.

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch(IllegalStateException e) {
   try {
      doAnotherThing();
  } catch(IOException e1) {
      throw new MyException(e1.getCause());
  }
  throw new MyException(e.getCause());
}
```

So how to preserve the stack trace in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You should be throwing MyException(e) and MyException(e1), respectively.

Comment: I've change my code to `try {
  doSomething();
} catch(IllegalStateException e) {
   try {
      doAnotherThing();
  } catch(IOException e1) {
      throw new MyException(e1);
  }
  throw new MyException(e);
}` Still it gives me code violation...

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
throw new MyException(exception.getCause());
```

to

```
throw new MyException(exception);
```

This will keep the full stack trace.